# How to automatically google search each row in a text file

Tags: python, google-chrome

I have a set names on a text file. My purpose is to search each name (row in the text file) on google and record the very first link appears on the google search results. Is there any way to automatically execute this process with a script? Otherwise I have to type 1000 names one by one on google and list the first link :(

Answer (score 2):

Is there a way? Yes. Is there a super quick and easy way? I'm not too sure about that.

What I would do given the task is use [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for web-scraping. You could easily iterate through each line in your text file with a loop and then you could convert the phrase into Google-URL-friendly.

EX: Take the phrase "This is a test sentence", replace spaces with "+" and then add it to the end of a google search default URL. Like this:

https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=This+is+a+test+sentence

After that you find whatever the id or class is of the link of the first page of a Google result and code your program to return that information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python solution that searches each line of the txt file. This code opens 5 links at a time:

```
import webbrowser

def open_links(links):
  for link in links:
    webbrowser.open(link)
    
def read_lines_from_txt_file(file_path):
  with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

  return lines


if __name__ == '__main__':
  file_path = 'Your File name.txt' # Enter your file name and it should be at the same path as this file
  lines = read_lines_from_txt_file(file_path)
  for i in range(0,len(lines),5):
    l=[]
    for j in range(0,5):
        k="https://www.google.com/search?q="+str(lines[i+j])
        l.append(k)
    print(l)
    open_links(l)
    hy=input("5 links are opened press enter to continue")
```

Answer (score -1):

I did a search in bard and it gave a answer and i did some modifications and its working

python code:

```
import webbrowser

def open_links(links):
  """Opens the specified links in Chrome.

  Args:
    links: A list of strings, where each string is a URL.
  """

  for link in links:
    webbrowser.open(link)
    
def read_lines_from_txt_file(file_path):
  """Reads all lines from a txt file.

  Args:
    file_path: The path to the txt file.

  Returns:
    A list of strings, where each string is a line in the txt file.
  """

  with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

  return lines


if __name__ == '__main__':
  file_path = 'file_name.txt'
"""Enter File name"""
  lines = read_lines_from_txt_file(file_path)
 
  for i in range(0,len(lines)):
    k=["https://www.google.com/search?q="+str(lines[i])]
    print(k)
    open_links(k)
```

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow.

 I don't think this answers the question, in particular the part about
`record the very first link appears on the google search results.` Also, please note that answers generated by bard are [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy) on the site.